# Gradle Exec exit value, stdout and stderr not intercepted from bash script

Tags: gradle, exec, exit-code

I'm currently trying to get behind an error that only occurs in CI, thrown by a script, called by Gradle Exec with Gradle 7.5.

**The issue is, I can't see any error messages in the log as it seems they aren't picked up by Gradle.**

For that reason, I've created a small Gradle Plugin located in **buildSrc** and an .sh script located under **/scripts**

```groovy
import org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.condition.Os
import org.gradle.api.Plugin
import org.gradle.api.Project
import org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec


class ExecTestPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {

    private boolean ENABLE_CUSTOM_OUTPUT = true;

    @Override
    void apply(Project target) {
        target.tasks.register("testExec", Exec) {
            group = "other"
            workingDir(target.getProjectDir().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + "scripts")

            if (ENABLE_CUSTOM_OUTPUT) {
                standardOutput = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
                errorOutput = new ByteArrayOutputStream()

                doLast {
                    def result = standardOutput.toString()
                    println "the result value is: $result"

                    def error = standardOutput.toString()
                    println "the error value is: $error"

                    println "exit value: " + execResult.exitValue
                }
            }

            if (Os.isFamily(Os.FAMILY_WINDOWS)) {
                commandLine 'cmd', '/c', "test-failing-script.sh"
            } else {
                commandLine "sh", "-c", "test-failing-script.sh"
            }

            if (ENABLE_CUSTOM_OUTPUT) {
                ext.output = {
                    return standardOutput.toString()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**test-failing-script.sh**

```bash
set -e
set -o pipefail

echo -e This message goes who knows where
echo This message goes to stderr >&2
echo This message goes to stdout >&1

#curl -sf -o /dev/null http://google.com

exit 1;
```

If the flag is **disabled**, I'm getting **no output at all**

If the flag is **enabled**, I'm getting

```
the result value is: 
the error value is:
exit value: 0
```

I'm expecting exit value 1 and for both **stdout and stderr some messages**

**Why can't I get the right response message from the called script?**

Comment: If the script you're calling exits with an error code, then the output might not be produced. Try ignoring the exit value https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec:ignoreExitValue

Comment: @aSemy oh this indeed helped to make the error message visible. But is there another solution? Because I need my CI pipeline to fail if something does not work, and with that everything is green

Comment: I would 1. create [a custom task type](https://github.com/liutikas/gradle-best-practices/#create-custom-tasks), instead of an adhoc task, then 2. [inject](https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/custom_gradle_types.html#service_injection) `ExecOperations`, and use it to run [exec()](https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/javadoc/org/gradle/process/ExecOperations.html#exec-org.gradle.api.Action-). This will return an `ExecResult`, which provides an exit value.

Comment: There is also the incubating [`ProviderFactory.exec()`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/provider/ProviderFactory.html#exec-org.gradle.api.Action-), which I think might suit your needs better.

Answer (score 0):

It's some time ago, that I faced this issue. But I think the problem could be with `sh -c` not forwarding stdout and exit value. But I can't reproduce it right now. Might be it's fixed in a more recent version of Gradle. Try using Gradle 7.5

Comment: Thanks. I'm already on Gradle 7.5 - should've added this